# Не работает конструкция if!

Tags: c#, .net, консоль, if, rss

Пишу новостной парсер. Был старый метод получения данных из RSS,попроще, он работал. Вот он:

```
    public bool getNewArticles(string fileSource)
    {

        SampleContext pContext = new SampleContext();
        GetKeyWords kWordsGetter = new GetKeyWords();
        string head;
        string syn;
        string link;
        string date;
        string keyW;
        string chanelName;
        string[] sources =
        {
        "http://www.interfax.ru/rss.asp",
        "http://www.mk.ru/rss/politics/index.xml"
        };

         try
         {
             XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
             doc.Load(fileSource);

             XmlNodeList nodeList;
             XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
             nodeList = root.ChildNodes;
             int count = 0;

             foreach (XmlNode chanel in nodeList)
             {
                 foreach (XmlNode chanel_item in chanel)
                 {
                     if (chanel_item.Name == "item")
                     {
                         XmlNodeList itemsList = chanel_item.ChildNodes;

                         foreach (XmlNode item in itemsList)
                         {
                             if (item.Name == "title")
                             {
                                 head = item.InnerText;
                                Console.WriteLine(head);
                             }
                             if (item.Name == "link")
                             {
                                 link = item.InnerText;
                                Console.WriteLine(link);
                             }
                             if (item.Name == "description")
                             {
                                 syn = item.InnerText;
                             }
                             context.News.Add(new DB.Table()
                             {
                                 Id = count,
                                 Head = head,
                                 Link = link,
                                 Synopsis = syn
                             });

                             context.SaveChanges();
                         }
                         count += 1;
                     }


                 }
             }
             return true;
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             return false;
         }    
    }
}
```

Усовершенствовал метод, чтобы выделял из документа только политические новости посредством сравнения с категорией (item.Name = "category"), но код работать перестал, доходит только до title в документе, т.е. в консоль выдаёт head, а остальные if игнорирует. Вот усовершенствованный метод:

```
public bool getNewArticles(string fileSource)
    {

        SampleContext pContext = new SampleContext();
        GetKeyWords kWordsGetter = new GetKeyWords();
        string head;
        string syn;
        string link;
        string date;
        string keyW;
        string chanelName;
        string[] sources =
        {
        "http://www.interfax.ru/rss.asp",
        "http://www.mk.ru/rss/politics/index.xml"
        };

try
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlNodeList nodeList;
            XmlNode root;
            //string fileSource = "http://www.interfax.ru/rss.asp";
            //foreach (string fileSource in sources)
            {

                doc.Load(fileSource);

                root = doc.DocumentElement;
                nodeList = root.ChildNodes;
                foreach (XmlNode chanel in nodeList)
                {
                    foreach (XmlNode chanel_item in chanel)
                    {
                        if (chanel_item.Name == "title")
                        {
                            chanelName = chanel_item.InnerText;
                        }
                        if (chanel_item.Name == "item")
                        {
                            XmlNodeList itemsList = chanel_item.ChildNodes;
                            Console.WriteLine(5);

                            foreach (XmlNode item in itemsList)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(6);
                                if (item.Name == "title")
                                {
                                    head = item.InnerText;
                                    keyW = kWordsGetter.ToKWStr(head);
                                    Console.WriteLine(head);
                                }
                                if (item.Name == "link")
                                {
                                    link = item.InnerText;
                                    Console.WriteLine(link);
                                }
                                if (item.Name == "description")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(9);
                                    syn = item.InnerText;
                                }
                                if (item.Name == "pubDate")
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(10);
                                    date = item.InnerText;
                                }
                                if (item.Name == "category" & (item.InnerText == "В мире" 
         || item.InnerText == "В России" || item.InnerText == "Политика"))
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine(7);
                                }
                                else
                                    break;

                                pContext.pArticles.Add(new DB.PoliticsArticles()
                                {
                                    header = head,
                                    link = link,
                                    synopsis = syn,
                                    keyWords = keyW,
                                    dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(date),
                                    source = chanelName
                                });

                                pContext.SaveChanges();
                            }



                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Выдача такая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А точно никаких эксепшнов не вылетает? Добавьте в `catch` к `return false` вывод ошибки: `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())`

Comment: @Zufir добавил, ничего не поймалось

Comment: В .NET есть встроенные средства для работы с RSS. См. класс [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` работает. Проблема с циклом.
Если это не политическая новость - Вы просто выходите из цикла, обрабатывающего внутренние ноды item'а.
Замените `break` на `continue`. Это не даст выполнится коду добавления в базу, но не прекратит обработку списка.

> Оператор break завершает выполнение ближайшего оператора внешнего
>   цикла или switch, в котором он находится. Управление передается
>   оператору, который расположен после завершенного оператора.
>
> Оператор continue передает управление следующей итерации вложенного
>   оператора while, do, for или foreach, в котором она встречается.

Ну и операнд "и" в C# пишется как `&&`, а не как `&`.

P.S. И вынесите добавление в базу из `foreach`. Перед добавлением нужно заполнить все свойства.

Comment: по поводу оператора `&&` и `&`: оба могут использоваться как логическое "И", Просто `&` всегда вычисляет оба операнда, а `&&` вычисляет второй операнд только если первого недостаточно для окончательного ответа. Тоже касается операторов `||` и `|`. В остальном +.